# Changing brunch's conventions.assets isn't doing what I expect

Tags: brunch

I've read every bit of documentation I could find on this and I can't figure would what's wrong.

My file structure is like so:

```
project/
  brunch-config.js
  node_modules/
    ...
  package.json
  source/
    styles.css
    app.js
    index.html
```

Now I understand that by default all assets are supposed to be in `app/assets`, but I've changed `app/` to be called `source/` and I'd like to eliminate the need for an `source/assets` directory.

Therefore, my brunch-config.js file looks like so:

```
exports.config = {
    paths: {
        public: 'build',
        watched: ['source']
    },
    conventions: {
        ignored: () => false,
        assets: '*.html'
    },
    files: {
        javascripts: {joinTo: 'app.js'},
        stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
    }
};
```

All works like I want it to expect for the handling of assets. From all that I've read, I thought that changing `conventions.assets` default of `/assets\//` to `'*.html'` would cause any html file inside the `source` directory to be considered an asset. This is not what is happening.

Upon running `brunch watch --server`, the css and js files are compiled properly but the `index.html` file is never copied. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding how brunch is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expressions to match all HTML files: `assets: /\.html$/`

```
exports.config = {
    paths: {
        public: 'build',
        watched: ['source']
    },
    conventions: {
        ignored: () => false,
        assets: /\.html$/
    },
    files: {
        javascripts: {joinTo: 'app.js'},
        stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
    }
};
```